# Unity4.6のuGUIのCanvasのRender Cameraをスクリプトで変更したい

Tags: unity3d, ugui

Canvas の Render Mode は以下のような C# のスクリプトで変更できたのですが、

```
GameObject.Find("CanvasName").GetComponent<Canvas>().renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
GameObject.Find("CanvasName").GetComponent<Canvas>().renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceCamera;
```

Render Camera についてもスクリプトで変更したいのですが、うまくできないでおります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GameObject.Find("CanvasName").GetComponent<Canvas>().worldCamera = targetCamera;
```

worldCameraで設定できるみたいです

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまく動作しました。
---
書式もさることながら、そもそもカメラの指定が悪かった。
     private Camera targetCamera;
     ...
としないで、文字列で指定していた。

Comment: targetCamera = GameObject.Find ("Camera2").GetComponent<Camera> ();